# Interpolate / fillna with a decay formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,4, None, None, None, None, -1, 1, None, None])
>>> df
      0
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   4.0
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7  -1.0
8   1.0
9   NaN
10  NaN
```

I want to fill the missing values with an exponential decay starting from the previous value, giving:

```
>>> df_result
      0
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   4.0
3   4.0 # NaN replaced with previous value
4   2.0 # NaN replaced previous value / 2
5   1.0 # NaN replaced previous value / 2
6   0.5 # NaN replaced previous value / 2
7  -1.0
8   1.0
9   1.0 # NaN replaced previous value
10  0.5 # NaN replaced previous value / 2
```

With `fillna`, I have `method='pad'`, but I cannot fit my formula here.
With `interpolate`, I'm not sure I can give a specific exponential decay formula, and take into account only the last not-NaN value.

I'm thinking of creating a separate dataframe `df_replacements` initialised with `0.5` instead of the NaN and `0` elsewhere, do a cumprod (somehow I need to reset the running product to 1 for every first NaN), and then `df_result = df.fillna(df_replacements, inplace=True)`

Is there a simple way to achieve this replacement with pandas?

Answer (score 3):

In your case fill the nan forward, then we `groupby` to find the consecutive `NaN` , get the `cumcount`

```
s=df[0].ffill()
df[0].fillna(s[df[0].isnull()].mul((1/2)**(df[0].groupby(df[0].notnull().cumsum()).cumcount()-1),0))
Out[655]: 
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     4.0
3     4.0
4     2.0
5     1.0
6     0.5
7    -1.0
8     1.0
9     1.0
10    0.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

*Edit by OP: same solution with more explicit variables names:*

```
ffilled = df[0].ffill()
is_na = df[0].isnull()
group_ids = df[0].notnull().cumsum()
mul_factors = (1 / 2) ** (df[0].groupby(group_ids).cumcount() - 1)
result = df[0].fillna(ffilled[is_na].mul(mul_factors, 0))
```

Comment: Method chaining in its prime :)